# How to set second spinner adapter from first spinner with json data?

Tags: java, android, json, android-spinner

I have two spinners, I want to change the array adapter of the second spinner when certain item in spinner 1 is selected from json. I got the adapter working, but when I select the item in the second spinner, the second spinner item selected doesn't change.
and this my json :

```
[
   {
     "id":70,
     "name": "Jakarta",
     "wilayah":[
          {"id":15,
           "name":"Pasar Minggu",
           "parent":70
          },
          {"id":16,
           "name":"Duren Kalibata",
           "parent":70
          }
      ]
    },
    {
     "id":71,
     "name": "Jawa",
     "wilayah":[
          {"id":15,
           "name":"Depok",
           "parent":70
          },
          {"id":16,
           "name":"Bogor",
           "parent":70
          }
      ]
    }
]
```

**Code**

```
JSONArray data_prov = data_list.getJSONArray(0);
for (int i=0; i<data_prov.length();i++){
    JSONObject listprov = data_prov.getJSONObject(i);


    String prov = listprov.getString("name");

    arrayprov.add(prov);

    JSONArray data_wilayah = listprov.getJSONArray("wilayah");
    for (int j = 0; j < data_wilayah.length(); j++){
        JSONObject lisdes = data_desa.getJSONObject(j);

        String des = lisdes.getString("name");
        arraywilayah.add(des);
    }
}

spinner_prov.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(TambahActivity.this,
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, arraywilayah));
```

please Help me

Comment: You need to filter second spinner data using selected id of first spinner

Comment: What is your first adapter?